# How to use std::toupper in std::for_each?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'm trying to convert the lowercase characters of a string into its uppercase counterpart using the std::toupper function and I'm using the std::for_each algorithm to iterate over the characters in the string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>

std::string convert_toupper(std::string *x) {
  return std::toupper(*x, std::locale());
}

int main() {
  std::string x ("example");

  std::for_each(x.begin(), x.end(), convert_toupper);
}
```

When I compile this code I'm getting this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/algorithm:62:0,
                 from me2.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >; _Funct = std::basic_string<char> (*)(std::basic_string<char>*)]’:
me2.cpp:13:52:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algo.h:4417:14: error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>*’ [-fpermissive]
  __f(*__first);
              ^
```

What is the proper way of character conversion from lowercase to uppercase using std::toupper and std::for_each?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `string` is a container of `char`s, basically. When you iterate of a `string`, you are going one `char` at a time. So the functor you pass into `for_each` will be called with a `char`, not a `string*`, hence the error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘std::basic_string<char>*
```

The correct implementation would just be:

```
std::for_each(x.begin(), x.end(), std::toupper);
```

That, however, would do nothing. The return value of `toupper` would be ignored, and that function has no side effects. If you really wanted to actually *transform* the string into its upper case version, you would have to use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), std::toupper);
```

Or, to provde locale:

```
char locale_upper(char c) { return std::toupper(c, std::locale()); }
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), locale_upper);
```

Or, in C++11:

```
std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), [](char c){
    return std::toupper(c, std::locale());
});
```

At which point you might as well just use a `for`-loop:

```
for (char& c : x) {
    c = std::toupper(c, std::locale());
}
```

Comment: Without localization, I'd replace `std::toupper` by `::toupper` (from `<ctype.h>`). Otherwise, including `<locale>` will create an ambiguity when calling `std::transform` due to the impossibility of the latter to deduce the correct type of `std::toupper` (there will now be 2 functions, one in `<cctype>` and one in `<locale>`, with different signatures, so you'd have to manually specify the signature for the functor type).

Comment: @vsoftco: Not impossible, I think you can use a cast for that.

Comment: I think it would be legal to use `std::for_each` with a lambda `[](char& c){ c = std::toupper(c);}`. Although the other solutions `range-based for` are more elegant.

Comment: @JesseGood a lambda is OK, a cast is not (you have to specify the type as  otherwise the templated std::transform doesn't know which overload to pick; and specifying the type is a pain, since the functor is the last in the type parameter list).

Comment: You shouldn't pass a `char` to the one-argument version of `std::toupper` (or `::toupper`).

Comment: Why can't I write `std::transform(x.begin(), x.end(), x.begin(), std::bind(std::toupper(std::placeholders::_1, std::locale())));` ?

Comment: @Kyle_the_hacker Do you want people to understand your code?

Answer (score 0):

In `<locale>` you already have the `std::ctype::toupper` function transforming lowercase strings in uppercase. The function call is a bit tricky but it is very compact:

```
std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale()).toupper(&x[0], &x[0] + x.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to convert a lowercase string to uppercase using `std::for_each` and `std::toupper`.
The important thing is to remember to make the parameter in the lambda a char reference ie `(char& ch)`.

```
#include <algorithm>   // for_each
#include <cctype>      // toupper
#include <iostream>    // cout
#include <string>      // string

int main()
{
   std::string s{ "This is a test" };
   std::cout << s << '\n';
   
   std::for_each(s.begin(), s.end(),[] (char& ch) { ch = std::toupper(ch); } );   
      
   std::cout << s << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```